# php date comparison returns false

Tags: php, datetime

Please someone let me know what is wrong in below code.

comparision does not work, date_diff function outputs false

```
    $strtime = strtotime("2021-01-01");
    $rowdate = date("d-n-Y", $strtime);
    $nextmonthyear = date("d-n-Y", strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
    if ($rowdate > $nextmonthyear) {
        echo "cont";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to do `($strtime > strtotime('first day of +1 month'))`
then use the date function to format it for display

Answer (score 1):

If you show the *dates* you are comparing...

```
echo $rowdate."->".$nextmonthyear;
```

you get

```
01-1-2021->01-8-2020
```

BUT you are actually then comparing them as strings, which gets to the 8 and compares it to the 1 in the other date.

You should either use `Y-n-d` format for the dates, or better still just use the date values themselves...

```
$strtime = strtotime("2021-01-01");
$nextmonthyear = strtotime('first day of +1 month');
if ($strtime > $nextmonthyear) {
    echo "cont";
}
```

Comment: I actually thought I am comparing objects and not string. but for an object we need new keyword.. Got it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`date()`returns a string. If you want to compare them as dates instead of strings use `date_create_from_format()` instead.